# using apply_filters send_new_site_email, why not working

Tags: wordpress, filter, multisite

I have a multisite with a lot of sites on it, registered almost daily. I want to stop the automatic email being send for a new site.
I
n the codex, i found this filter:

```
apply_filters( 'send_new_site_email', bool $send, WP_Site $site, WP_User $user )
```

The first argument, $send, can be set to false. Then the mail will not be send.

So I am using the following add_filter function:

```
function disable_email($send,$site,$user){
    $send = false;
    return $send;
}
add_filter( 'send_new_site_email', 'disable_email',10,3 );
```

Why does this not work?

Comment: Btw you can use the magic `__return_false` like this `add_filter( 'send_new_site_email', '__return_false', 99 );`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to increase priority, may be then it will work try something

add_filter( 'send_new_site_email', 'disable_email',25,3 );